# How do I handle and implement new and existing users within my MVC 6 app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

Using the built in Visual Studio 2015 generated MVC 6 scaffolding, how do I implement new users and handle existing users within my application?

I need to link registered users in the AspNetUsers to the person model that I have set up to add various additional properties.

I tried starting from OAuth, but I can't even seem to do this with the regular login and registration method. I found [one site](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1229/user-authentication-aspnet-mvc-6-identity) that explains this but I'm new to this and he starts with an empty project rather than the default MVC project so it's out of the context of my existing app and I don't know how to start blank like that, I'm not that advanced.

I have a person model with basic properties such as first and last name, and I can register new users. Oauth aside, how do I:

- Create a new person when the new user is registered.
- Link that person with the newly registered user so that the
  registered user is the owner of that person.
- Set up permissions for that user.

Is there a tutorial for this?

Person Model:

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The First Name field is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Last Name field is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With MVC6 starter project you only need to map your person class to the ASPNETUsers Model available. I think you would have extended person class from it from tutorial. If you have done that it would have quite a lot of methods available to it.
Have a look at this [example of IdentitModel](https://github.com/AlexChesser/MVC6-beta6/blob/master/src/MVC6-beta6/Models/IdentityModels.cs). Look into its controller for Registeration of Users and how identity is used to [Register](https://github.com/AlexChesser/MVC6-beta6/blob/master/src/MVC6-beta6/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L100) new users etc.

You might have to do some work on UI however this project and there are some others on github that can help you understand how this can be implemented and once you get the gist of it you will be enjoying with user management.

Just to add for tutorials you can [see this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1229/user-authentication-aspnet-mvc-6-identity) or if you use keywords like Identity MVC6 and Extending Identity models, you will see many basic tutorials online. User Management has gone through many changes so read a little bit to get hold of what current landscape is and then search for tutorials on those keywords. ASP.net has some sample projects that can help you a lot if you can setup on local machine and peek into code.

Comment: Thanks I linked that tutorial in the question, but it wasn't helpful since it starts blank. I only wish the tutorial I'd used to learn all this had gone into this.

Comment: Dont worry all you need is to inherit from Identity Model and you will have all ASP.net Identity functions available to you. User Management can be a small project in one solution with its own data and visual layers so dont worry about blank tutorial just focus on trying, failing and learning.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty much failing without learning here at this point. Nobody has an answer that is in the context of the built in mvc 6 scaffolding Visual Studio creates, it's all blank context and targeted to a pretty advanced crowd of devs, not beginners. Those githubs you linked I'm pretty confused about, I don't see what's going on there. I tried searching google for Extending identity models but again, same problem, out of context, blank and often not relevant. At this point I may just hire a tutor to screenshare with me for a while.

Comment: or get a subscription to pluralsight that has great courses. In One month you would see all this in action and you can learn anytime and watch it again and again. Its worth it.